# Issue in installing Ubuntu with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Gnome (on Windows 10), but once I pressed `F12` key, I obtained the following picture:

[image: boot menu]

Each time I selected my USB device, it brought me back in the exact same image. Yet I have well installed Ubuntu on that key [following these instructions](https://techlog360.com/how-to-dual-boot-kali-linux-v2-0-with-windows-10/).

Could anyone be able to tell me why I am not able to install Ubuntu? What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can have only a maximum of 3 devices in your computer's Boot Menu. Disconnect the G-Drive mobile USB HDD if you are not using it to install Ubuntu, so that the Ubuntu GNOME live USB will be able to be shown in the Boot Menu.
2. Make sure that the Ubuntu live USB is inserted all the way into the USB port, so that it will be detected when the computer starts up.
3. The Ubuntu installation media should be set as the first device in the Boot Menu.
4. Use a cheap flash drive instead of an external hard drive with spinning disks as the Ubuntu installation media. A flash drive is faster than an HDD and works better as Ubuntu installation media.
5. [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) is more specific to your situation than the Kali Linux tutorial that you have been following.